# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

Tags: ios

I am getting below raw error in crashlytics.

basically I am trying to calculate the label height in tableview's "heightForRowAtIndexPath" by assigning same text to another uilabel and getting its height in return, so i can assign height to cell accordingly

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000193533270 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001935d1228 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001934aab18 abort + 112
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x000000019356e3e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x000000019356d2f8 nano_free + 192
5  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018258d444 CFRelease + 1064
6  CoreText                       0x00000001830a1c18 TLine::~TLine() + 192
7  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018258d164 CFRelease + 328
8  UIFoundation                   0x000000018f697c68 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 15728
9  UIFoundation                   0x000000018f699c8c -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 636
10 UIKit                          0x0000000186e672f0 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 384
11 UIKit                          0x0000000186e67168 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 28
12 UIKit                          0x0000000186e670e4 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 136
13 UIKit                          0x0000000186e66f84 -[UIView(Geometry) sizeToFit] + 136
14 Shaadi                         0x000000010015fb70 -[ProfileDetailsView heightOfLabelNew:withWidth:withLines:] (ProfileDetailsView.m:674)
15 Shaadi                         0x000000010016058c -[ProfileDetailsView tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] (ProfileDetailsView.m:808)
16 UIKit                          0x0000000186f75b7c __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 500
17 UIKit                          0x0000000186f379bc -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3872
18 UIKit                          0x00000001872411e8 -[UITableViewRowData _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 180
19 UIKit                          0x0000000186f36a04 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 396
20 UIKit                          0x0000000186f36814 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 64
21 UIKit                          0x0000000186f36620 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 244
22 UIKit                          0x0000000186f3c5f4 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 88
23 UIKit                          0x0000000186e595f8 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1464
24 UIKit                          0x0000000186e7aa34 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 68
25 UIKit                          0x0000000186e59310 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
26 UIKit                          0x0000000186e589e0 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 144
27 UIKit                          0x0000000186e588c0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 484
28 UIKit                          0x0000000186e643a0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1764
29 Shaadi                         0x000000010020a148 -[PartnerProfileViewController addFullProfileDetailsAtPage:profileDetails:] (PartnerProfileViewController.m:838)
30 Shaadi                         0x0000000100209bf8 __62-[PartnerProfileViewController addProfilePage:profileDetails:]_block_invoke (PartnerProfileViewController.m:782)
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001933f13ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001933f136c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001933f5980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
34 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182665fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
35 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018266404c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
36 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001825910a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
37 GraphicsServices               0x000000018b7335a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
38 UIKit                          0x0000000186ec2aa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
39 Shaadi                         0x00000001001b2b64 main (main.m:16)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019341aa08 start + 4
```

I am unable to understand the cause of this error but it seems to happen at [uilable sizeToFit]

please help me understand what can be the cause of this.

======== Update ==========

```
-(NSMutableArray *)heightOfLabelNew:(NSString *)plainTxt withWidth:    (CGFloat)width withLines:(int)lines
{
    NSMutableArray *heights = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UILabel *tmpLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 20)];
    tmpLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
    tmpLbl.attributedText = [self getAttributedString:plainTxt];
    tmpLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    tmpLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [tmpLbl sizeToFit];


    [heights addObject:[NSNumber     numberWithFloat:tmpLbl.frame.size.height]];

    tmpLbl.numberOfLines = lines;
    [tmpLbl sizeToFit];

    [heights addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tmpLbl.frame.size.height]];

    return heights;
}


-(NSMutableAttributedString *)getAttributedString:(NSString *)text
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =       [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:3];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

    return attributedString;
}
```

Crashlytics show line number of code "[tmpLbl sizeToFit];"

Comment: And what does exception say? Also please post `ProfileDetailsView heightOfLabelNew:withWidth:withLines:` if possible.

Comment: @ Timur Kuchkarov : I have edited the question

Comment: You haven't posted the log output of xcode but – just to make sure conditions are okay – you always need to implement both methods: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; as well as

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: What value have number of lines and width (and what sizeToFit it crashes - there are two of them)? Also check this part with Zombies instrument, there may be some dead objects, although it looks unlikely here.